# Can we input AWS SSM Send command in Python script and can we that python script in AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I have below 2 AWS SSM command can I input these 2 commands in Python script and can i run same python script from AWS CLI?

if Yes, what would be pre requisites and python Syntax.

aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --document-version "1" --targets '[{"Key":"tag:AppD:Application","Values":["int-b"]},{"Key":"tag:AppD:Tier","Values":["wcsprimary-live"]}]' --cli-input-json file://./Scripts/auto_prop_live.json --comment "DB Auto_prop live" --timeout-seconds 43200 --max-concurrency "100%" --max-errors "1" --region ap-southeast-2
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --document-version "1" --targets '[{"Key":"tag:AppD:Application","Values":["int-b"]},{"Key":"tag:AppD:Tier","Values":["wcsprimary-stage"]}]' --cli-input-json file://./Scripts/auto_prop_stage.json --comment "DB Auto_prop stage" --timeout-seconds 43200 --max-concurrency "100%" --max-errors "1" --region ap-southeast-2